# Is there a Chrome equivalent of FireFTP add-on for Firefox?

Tags: chrome, ftp

This [has been asked many years ago](https://superuser.com/questions/202217/is-there-a-chrome-browser-extension-like-fireftp-from-firefox?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and I was thinking maybe things changed since then? I can't find much on Google, yet I can't believe nobody has done it. There must be something out there.

Comment: I'm not following. I'm looking for a Chrome extension.

Comment: My bad, I was reading backwards or something stupid like that.